# Equivalent diag R function in numpy python

Tags: python, r, numpy, diagonal

When I do with R `diag(0.03,2)` I obtain :

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.03 0.00
[2,] 0.00 0.03
```

How can I have the same result in Python ? I tried `numpy.diag(0.03,2)` but I get an error : `ValueError: Input must be 1- or 2-d`. Same with `numpy.diagonal(0.03,2)`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `numpy.diag([.03]*2)`.

`numpy.diag()` takes in a list of the diagonal components, and you can multiply lists in python to repeat elements.

Comment: Another way of spelling this is `np.diag(np.full(2, 0.3))`, which has the advantage of not creating a memory-inefficient python list, at least for `N>>2`

Comment: It seems that `np.eye(2) * .03` or `np.identity(2) * .03` will also produce the same results, though this is equivalent to `diag(2) * 0.3` in R.